# Webservices for enrolling Device under Company Apps in Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows, windows-8, mdm

Can we use simple java restful webservices to enroll the device under company apps in windows phone 8 devices.
I had tried with php and getting the proper requests but no luck with java my webservices are not even getting a hit from company apps.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Yes we can use the simple java REST webservices for enrolling the device under Company Apps account.